# Too may redirects when i use the wp_redirect() function

Tags: wp-redirect

I want my plugin to redirect to a page when some conditions are not met after plugin activation. I keep getting `To many redirects...` error message.

My code is as shown below:

```
if (! defined('WPINC')) die;
if (! class_exists('AwesomePlugin')) {

    class AwesomePlugin {
        public function __construct(){
            //Register admin menus
            add_action('admin_menu', [$this, add_menu]);

            //Init plugin
            add_action('admin_init', [$this, 'init_plugin']);
        }

        /**
         *
         * Init plugin
         */
        public function init_plugin(){
            if(!isset(get_option("some_option"))){
                wp_redirect("admin.php?page=some-page"); exit; //This gives too many redirects
            }
            wp_redirect('admin.php?page=dashboard'); exit;
        }

        /**
         * Add menu and submenu items 
         */
        public function add_menu(){
            add_menu_page( 
                'Dashboard', 'Dashboard', 'manage_options', 'dashboard', 
                [__CLASS__, 'load_dashboard_view'], 
                plugins_url('logo.png', __FILE__)
            );

            add_submenu_page(
                '', 'Signup page', 'Signup page', 'manage_options', 
                'sign-up', [__CLASS__, 'load_signup_view']
            ); 
        }  

        /**
         * Dashboard page 
         */
        public function load_dashboard_view(){
            include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'dashboard.php');
        } 

        /**
         * Signup page
         */
        public function load_signup_view(){
            include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'signup.php');
        }           
    } 

    AwesomePlugin()   
}
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** I understand that no matter the page I'm loading, the `init_plugin` function keeps firing. As a result, it keeps redirecting the user to the `sign-up`, thus the `many redirect` error message. How do I solve this?

Comment: You code perform a redirect if `some_option` is not set on every admin page load, it you don't set it up, the condition to redirect will be always `true` in every page load. You just need to think about a proper workflow for your purpose, which is what?

Answer (score -1):

This will help you want you want to achieve.

```
// Add option
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'me_shakeeb_install' );
function me_shakeeb_install() {

    $result = 'signup'; // Perform your logic here to decide where to redirect
    add_option( 'me_shakeeb_redirect_to', $result );
}

// Check Option
add_action( 'init', 'me_shakeeb_signup_check' );
function me_shakeeb_signup_check() {

    /**
     * Redirect to about page.
     */
    if ( false !== get_option( 'me_shakeeb_redirect_to', false ) ) {
        $page = get_option( 'me_shakeeb_redirect_to', false );
        delete_option( 'me_shakeeb_redirect_to' );
        wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=$page' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```